# JS/jQuery security

Tags: php, jquery, security

As a beginner, I'm always wondering if what I'm doing is actually secure. For example, recently I finished working on some code which checks how many times a (cross-domain) iframe has been clicked. And when clicked, inserting a row into a MySQL (log) table based on an ajax request(with jquery) which wraps the ID of the iframe into a $_POST:

```
$.ajax({ 
        url: 'execute.php',
        data: {action: 'some-id'},
        type: 'post'
    });
```

However I'm wondering: Because JavaScript is executed client-side, is it possible for a user to send **fake data** through the ajax request to the 'execute.php' page?

Comment: It absolutely is possible, that's why you should always check the data in your PHP code.

Comment: Yes; you cannot trust any data that comes from the client.

Comment: A client can completely ignore whatever your code does and send any arbitrary data to that endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible for a user to send fake data through the ajax request to the 'execute.php' page?

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible for a user to send fake data through the ajax request to the 'execute.php' page?

It is completely possible, you should add validations on the server.

For example, if i go to your site, open the console and write this code:

```
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'execute.php',
        data: {action: '1'},
        type: 'post'
    });
```

It will send a request to your execute.php sending the info `action=1`.